# Inserting an Image From Google Drive or from a URL into Google Sheets with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I was using this script below to insert images from a URL into specified cells in Google Sheets, however, it won't work for image URLs contained within Google Drive.

```
//If any graphic is a URL, insert that URL into the corresponding cell in the Briefing tab.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var source = ss.getSheetByName("main_gen").getRange("ImageRange").getValues();
  var dstSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Briefing");
  for (var num = 0; num < source.length; num ++) {
    if (/https?:\/\//.test(source[num][0])) { //Check to ensure a URL has been entered.
      var graphicformula = '=IMAGE("' + source[num][0] + '",1)';
      dstSheet.getRange(graphics_placements[num]).setFormula(graphicformula);
    }
  }
```

The user enters the URL of images in a predefined number of cells on one tab. Based on the order they select (there can be anywhere from 1 to 5 images), the images are inserted in specified cells on another tab. How could I rewrite the above code to account for both a URL like this (https://google.com/image.png) and like this (https://drive.google.com/open?id=12Au6IQE9l9X_hzM5n87Fs9gajJ)?

Thanks!

Comment: I can understand about the URL of `https://drive.google.com/open?id=###`. But I cannot understand about the URL of `https://google.com/image.png`. So can I ask you about it? For example, can you provide the sample URL of `https://google.com/image.png`?

Comment: @Tanaike It could be any image from online such as: https://neilpatel.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/google.jpg.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In that case, the URL can be used for `=IMAGE()`. In your question, you want to use such URL and the URL of `https://drive.google.com/open?id=###`. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Correct. I need a script that will account for either one of those URLs.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I thought that  I could correctly understand about your question. So I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- You want to put the image files in your Google Drive to the Spreadsheet using the formula of `IMAGE()`.

  - In your case, the URL is like `https://google.com/image.png` and `https://drive.google.com/open?id=###`.
  - `https://google.com/image.png` is the external link.
  - `https://drive.google.com/open?id=###` is the link in your Google Drive.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Issue and workaround:

Unfortunately, the image files in the Google Drive cannot be directly put to the Spreadsheet using `IMAGE()`. In this case, the image files are required to be publicly shared. So in this answer, the files are publicly shared and put to the Spreadsheet.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, please modify as follows.

From:

```
for (var num = 0; num < source.length; num ++) {
  if (/https?:\/\//.test(source[num][0])) { //Check to ensure a URL has been entered.
    var graphicformula = '=IMAGE("' + source[num][0] + '",1)';
    dstSheet.getRange(graphics_placements[num]).setFormula(graphicformula);
  }
}
```

To:

```
for (var num = 0; num < source.length; num ++) {
  if (/https?:\/\//.test(source[num][0])) { //Check to ensure a URL has been entered.
    var res = source[num][0].match(/drive\.google\.com\/open\?id=(\w.+)|drive\.google\.com\/file\/d\/(\w.+)\//);
    if (res && res.length > 0) {
      var id = res[1] || res[2];
      var file = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
      if (file.getOwner().getEmail() != Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()) {
        file = file.makeCopy(DriveApp.getRootFolder());
      }
      file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);
      source[num][0] = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=" + id;
    }
    var graphicformula = '=IMAGE("' + source[num][0] + '",1)';
    dstSheet.getRange(dstSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1).setFormula(graphicformula);
  }
}
```

- In the sample, when the owner of the file is different from you, the file is copied to the root folder of your Google Drive. When you want to put the specific folder, please modify `DriveApp.getRootFolder()`.

#### Note:

- If the URLs except for the pattern of `https://drive.google.com/open?id=###` are included, please show the sample URLs.

#### Reference:

- [setSharing(accessType, permissionType)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#setsharingaccesstype,-permissiontype)

### Added:

Please modify the for loop in your script as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
var scale = 0.5; // In this case, the imported image is reduces with 50 % from the original size.
var n = 0;
var cellWidth = 0;
for (var num = 0; num < source.length; num ++) {
  if (/https?:\/\//.test(source[num][0])) { //Check to ensure a URL has been entered.
    var res = source[num][0].match(/drive\.google\.com\/open\?id=(\w.+)|drive\.google\.com\/file\/d\/(\w.+)\//);
    var blob = res && res.length > 0 ? DriveApp.getFileById(res[1] || res[2]).getBlob() : UrlFetchApp.fetch(source[num][0]).getBlob();
    var lastRow = dstSheet.getLastRow() + 1 + n++;
    var image = dstSheet.insertImage(blob, 1, lastRow);
    var imageWidth = image.getWidth() * scale;
    var imageHeight = image.getHeight() * scale;
    cellWidth = cellWidth > imageWidth ? cellWidth : imageWidth;
    image.setWidth(imageWidth);
    image.setHeight(imageHeight);
    dstSheet.setRowHeight(lastRow, imageHeight);
  }
}
dstSheet.setColumnWidth(1, cellWidth);
```

- In this case, the image is put on the cell. This is put not in the cell. So when you want to match the image size to the cell size, the cell size is required to be changed. In above script, `dstSheet.setRowHeight(lastRow, imageHeight)` and `dstSheet.setColumnWidth(1, cellWidth)` change the cell size.

Comment: Ok, I see what path you are taking. When I run this I get Access Denied. The Google Drive Folder I am accessing the images from I do not own, but do have view privileges. I assume I am getting this error because I do not own the folder, therefore I cannot set the permission of the images?

Comment: @hunter21188 Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. In that case, how about copying it to your Google Drive and sharing publicly? For this, I modified the sample script. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you want, I apologize, again.

Comment: Appreciate all the help! Unfortunately that still gives me the same error. This is an example of one of the links (https://drive.google.com/file/d/12Au6IQE9l9X_hzM5n87Fs9gajJ_9VjWi/view). Not sure if that helps you at all or not to understand why I might still be getting these permission issues. I can view the image just fine with my google account.

Comment: @hunter21188 Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize for the inconvenience. About `https://drive.google.com/file/d/12Au6IQE9l9X_hzM5n87Fs9gajJ_9VjWi/view`, this is the different pattern from your question. I couldn't notice about existing such other patterns. This is due to my poor skill. I apologize for this. I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? If this didn't resolve your issue, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet? By this, I would like to confirm it. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: Found the issue with that problem. I had to change it to `DOMAIN_WITH_LINK` since that is how it is restricted. That does fill in cells (though not the correct cells) with the code (for example) `=IMAGE("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=12Au6IQE9l9X_hzM5n87Fs9gajJ_9VjWi",1)`. However, the cells are blank. When I try to access that link directly, it says I do not have permission. Unfortunately sharing a sample spreadsheet won't help as I created one and it works fine (though still not inserting images in the right cells). It has to do with the Domain issue :/

Comment: Perhaps it could help in some way, so here is an example sheet (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1x3uy33Ol0XFUuQbLtQ84zv4zJ2RRof1eJ5yKxLruFUY/edit?usp=sharing). Run the "Create Briefing" script to run the code. The aforementioned code starts on line 530.

Comment: @hunter21188 Thank you for replying. From your replying, I would like to confirm the following points. 1. Can you copy the file of `https://drive.google.com/file/d/###/view` to your Google Drive? 2. In your situation, when the image file in your Google Drive is publicly shared, can the image be putting using the url of `https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=###` with `=IMAGE()`?

Comment: @hunter21188 If one of 2 points cannot be achieved, in your case, for example, how about using the external cloud storage which can be publicly shared with the URL, or using Google Drive of the Google account which is the independent, or using the image file as the blob instead of `=IMAGE()`? If these were not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Yes, the image can be inserted and viewed with the url of  `https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=###` with `=IMAGE()` when it is stored on my personal Google Drive (unfortunately, it will have to only be stored on the DOMAIN server and not on a personal account). Of the possible solutions you mentioned, I feel like the blob would be the best way to go as the others are not an option, but I am not sure exactly what you mean by that? Thanks again!

Comment: @hunter21188 Thank you for replying. About the method for using the blob, although I'm not sure whether this is the result you want, I added one more sample script. In this case, when the file can be read, the blob can be retrieved. And in the current stage, after the images are put as the blob, at first, please open the other sheet in the same Spreadsheet, and then, please back to the sheet. By this, the images can be shown. I think that this might be a bug.

Comment: Your newest solution does indeed work. I saw in the documentation they still have no way to insert the image in cell via the `insertImage` function. That certainly makes you wonder if it is a bug with the other method, because that would be the way I would need to go with the image being inserted into the cell. Regardless, I will mark that as an accepted answer since it does work with the second solution. Thank you so much!

Comment: @hunter21188 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.